# В базу данных попадают непонятные значения

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Вообщем в чём суть. Имею код:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['token'])){

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$subject = 'тут тема письма';
$message = 'тут текст письма';

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_base = '';
$db_table = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password, $db_base);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_error .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (login,password,email,phone) VALUES ('$login','$password','$email','$phone')");
if ($result == true){
    echo 'Информация занесена в базу данных, на указаный вами e-mail был выслат уникальный код, сохраните его, пожалуйста..';
}else{
    echo 'Информация не занесена в базу данных. ', $mysqli->error;
}
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
mail($email, $subject, $message)
?>
```

Если во всех полях написать 123, то заходя в базу данных отправились правильные 123. А если написать в полях свой никнейм, пароль, почту, телефон, то при входе в базу данных во всех полях кроме телефона стоит 0, а в поле телефона цифры которые явно не сопадают с теми,которые я заносил в поле. Помогите знающие

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите переменные PHP внутри SQL запросов. Это не безопасно.

Comment: покажите структуру таблицы

Comment: Оно? https://ibb.co/gYX0AK  Забыл в код php файла поле token добавить, добавил - ничего не поменялось, в поле по прежнему 0. UPD. моё предположение - ошибка в типе столбов в таблице. Верно?

Comment: ))) все поля в БД числовые!! конечно туда ни одной буквы не попадет!! и еще - у вас переменная $message ГДЕ формируется?? надо её формировать, иначе сбой скрипта. И вообщеоткуда это поделие скоипровали?? защиты от иньекции нет, в условие if (isset...) {} надо включать и отправку на почту!.А у вас отправка (вернее, попытка отправки) идет в любом случае, при этом переменные не определены!!!

Comment: "был выслат" +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_base = '';
$ = '';
```

Не указаны параметры для подключения к базе, а также для работы переменных в кавычках их необходимо заключать в двойные ".

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (login,password,email,phone) VALUES ('$login','$password','$email','$phone')");
```